# Android OCR detecting digits only using popular tessercat fork tess-two

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I'm using the popular OCR tessercat fork for android tess-two https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two. I integrated all the staff and it works etc...

But I need to detect only digits, my code for now is:

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.init(pathToLngFile, langName);
baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
baseApi.end();
doSomething(recognizedText);
```

From here https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits?

I'm using version V3, and there ain't code solution instead some command line solution - not relevant for android project (I think...). So I tried to implement the solution for version < V3 and add this line:

```
baseApi.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

My question is what to do with the init()? I don't need any language, but still I need to init & aint init() method...

EDIT: To be more specific

My end goal is plain document (not pure Excel sheet), that looks like the attached picture (header & 3 columns separated by white spaces).

My requirements is to make sense in the digits: To be able to separate and determine which digits belong to which row and column. 
[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to do the same and after a bit of research I decided to capture all, text and numbers, and then just keep the numbers, this is working for me:

```
//This Replaces all except numbers from 0 to 9    
recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
```

And now you can do whatever you want with the numbers.

For example, I use this code to get all the numbers separated into an String array, and show them on a TextView

```
String[] justnumbers = recognizedText.trim().split(" "); //Deletes blank spaces and splits the numbers
YourTextView.setText(Arrays.toString(justnumbers).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "")) //sets the numbers into the TextView and deletes the "[]" from the String Array
```

You can see it working [here](http://ideone.com/wUpUN1).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I made it a bit different. Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

So you need to initialize first the API.

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.init(datapath, language, ocrEngineMode);
```

Then set the following variables

```
baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_LINE);
baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, "!?@#$%&*()<>_-+=/:;'\"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, ".,0123456789");
baseApi.setVariable("classify_bln_numeric_mode", "1");
```

In this way the engine will check only the numbers.

Comment: Thanks it worked ! but the result are false... the reconiction is not as good as for the text..

Comment: Any solution for false result?