# How can I be output Android only numbers in OCR?

Tags: android, numbers, ocr, tess-two

I am developing an Android OCR.

Using tess-two in the Android made ​​the OCR.

I have downloaded the 'traineddata' [file](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR.). And it has succeeded in output in English . But I want to output a number.

In the Internet gave me inform the sentence 'tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits' and it has advised me to insert the generated files.

But I did not understand what I'm saying .
Please tell me the easiest way.

Comment: `But I did not understand what I'm saying ` - interesting problem)

Comment: haha... I can not speak English well , so I am using a translator .  >> I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set `tessedit_char_whitelist` variable, as follows:

```
baseApi.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

See [Android OCR detecting digits only using popular tessercat fork tess-two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890204/android-ocr-detecting-digits-only-using-popular-tessercat-fork-tess-two) or [extracting numbers from Bitmap in android using tess-two library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755076/extracting-numbers-from-bitmap-in-android-using-tess-two-library).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness!